# Dreamweaver ASP Page connecting to SQL Server - Login Failed for 'NT Authority\IUSR'

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp-classic, dreamweaver

I am trying to connect an .ASP page created in Dreamweaver. I am using an FTP connection from Dreamweaver to my server which is working fine, but when I build the database connection using ODBC, I get the following error

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'.

Any suggestions on how to get round this?

Answer (score 0):

I added a new user in SQL, and this appears to have worked.